# Query Values Muliple Field Foreign Key Column

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

This is my model:

```
class Personel(models.Model):
    Numara = models.IntegerField(max_length=10)
    Isim = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    Soyisim = models.CharField(max_length=30)


class Islem(models.Model):
    MenuAd = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    Tarih = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    Personel = models.ForeignKey(Personel)
    Durum = models.PositiveIntegerField(max_length=5)
```

This is my query:

```
sorgu = Islem.objects.all().values('MenuAd', 'Personel')
```

sorgu result:

```
[{'MenuAd': 'Deneme', 'Personel': 2 }]
```

but, i want to result:

```
[{'MenuAd': 'Deneme', 'Personel': '2 - Baris Halici'}]
```

Numara: 2
Isim: Baris
Soyisim: Halici

example - proposal

```
def get_full_personel(self):
    return "'%s - %s %s" % (self.Numara, self.Isim, self.Soyisim)
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try changing your:

```
class Personel(models.Model):
    def __unicode___(self):
        return "'%s - %s %s" % (self.Numara, self.Isim, self.Soyisim)
```

or `___str___(self):` if using python 3.

although that may not solve it... try:

```
sorgu = Islem.objects.all().values('MenuAd', 'Personel__get_full_personel')
```

Comment: hi, thank you for answer. but, i am using python 2.7 :-( i need to do what?

Comment: so set the unicode function or the last method of selection of a related column